# Calling a method after drawing a map region with setRegion:animated: in iOS

Tags: ios, callback, drawing, mkmapview, hud

Is it possible to know when `mapView` will complete the drawing a map after calling `setRegion` method?

I show the `HUD` before calculating region parameters:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Finding"];

MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;

newRegion.center.latitude     = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
newRegion.center.longitude    = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;
newRegion.span.latitudeDelta  = maxLat - minLat;
newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = maxLon - minLon;
```

then setting a new region and hiding the `HUD`:

```
[self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:NO];
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

But HUD dismisses faster than a new region appears on the map. How to dismiss the `HUD` after drawing? Is it any callback for `setRegion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKMapViewDelegate has mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated: that will be called when your MKMapView has moved to the specified region.

ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

Answer (score 1):

`– mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:` of `MKMapViewDelegate` can be used to execute code after loading of the map finished.

Answer (score -2):

[SVProgressHUD performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
Details [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)